# Color raw diff output with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, colors, diff

I've got the result of a diff between two files that I'm showing a user. Is there any JS library that could be used to color the raw diff text (by adding the necessary HTML) so that added and removed lines are colored properly?

The raw diff text has a format similar to the following:

```
####----
--- /path/to/some/file  2014-09-02 10:22:17.273600883 -0400
+++ /path/to/some/file  2014-09-02 10:24:20.404052923 -0400
@@ -123,12 +123,14 @@

-This line was removed
-This line was also removed
+This line was added
+I added this line, too
```

I'd prefer a JS solution, but am open to a PHP one as well.

Comment: I'd do this in PHP, using custom tags around your colored text areas and a css file

Comment: how are you "showing?"

Comment: @David If you mean in terms of UI, it's in a lightbox. In terms of data, I make an AJAX request to a PHP script which returns the text.

Comment: Got it. So you already have it as a JavaScript string and are trying to figure out how to throw it up there?

Comment: @David Right, it's already in a string. My concern was if there was an existing JS library that could add the HTML necessary to that string to add color when displayed. I couldn't find one while searching.

Comment: What is the name of the library tyou are using for the diff? Sorry for the off topic, but all the diff libraries I found are using HTML output and I need raw deltas to store in the DB. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the [Colorer Take 5 library](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/) can colour patches (I don't know if it is still really active though).

Ooops, Colorer Take5 is C++. This is [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) that you want.